# Word to describe something that opens like a book?

Tags: single-word-requests

More specifically, something with bound pages that inherently has a "front" and a "back", in which you start by looking at the "front" and flipping the pages over to see the back of that page and the front of the next.  You know.. like a book.  Book-like?

Is there a single word or technical phrase to describe this unambiguously?

Comment: I can only think of "bound" that you use - or maybe "leaved"...?

Comment: Provide some context for how you are looking to use this word, and you will likely get more help.

Comment: What object do you want to define with this word? Do you want to define something with pages? For example, you can consider "paged". There are also terms like flip book, flip cover. So "flip" can be your choice, but it doesn't connote that there are pages.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in terms of a technical document:  The device shall be 5 inches by 7 inches and [open like a book].

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for "codex".

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex)

[Wiktionary link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/codex)

Answer (score 0):

> Tome, album, manual, anthology, publication, or ledger

As @Drew and @ermanen state, if you can define said object, more answers will follow.  It stands as a riddle: What is bound, has a back, front, and pages like a book, but isn't?

Answer (score 0):

The word "[folio](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/folio)" might serve your purpose. The definition closely matches what you've described.